# Why a nested QStateMachine inside subclass of QState with this pointer in constructor causes that an outer state machine can't make a transition?

Tags: c++, qt, state-machine

There is a state machine (called the outer). This machine has two states - first and the final. First state is custom implemented. Inside the first state there is created another state machine (called the inner) which in this example does nothing.

Outer state machine with two states:

```
  #include <QDebug>
  #include <QCoreApplication>
  #include <QTimer>
  #include <custom_outer_state.hpp>
  #include <QFinalState>
  #include "a.hpp"

  class Functor
  {
  public:
     void operator()()
     {
        // just emits a signal
        TestObject outerTestObject;

        // create outer state machine with all states
        QStateMachine outerStateMachine;
        CustomOuterState *state1 = new CustomOuterState();
        QFinalState *state2 = new QFinalState();
        state1->addTransition(&outerTestObject, SIGNAL(testObjectSignal()), state2);
        outerStateMachine.addState(state1);
        outerStateMachine.addState(state2);
        outerStateMachine.setInitialState(state1);
        outerStateMachine.start();

        // process state machine transitions
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        qDebug() << &outerStateMachine << ": Outer state machine first state " <<  outerStateMachine.configuration();
        outerTestObject.testObjectSignal();
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        qDebug() << &outerStateMachine << ": Outer state machine second state " <<  outerStateMachine.configuration();
     }
  };

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTimer::singleShot(0, Functor());
    return QCoreApplication::exec();
  }
```

And custom state:

```
  #ifndef CUSTOM_OUTER_STATE_H
  #define CUSTOM_OUTER_STATE_H

  #include <QState>
  #include <QStateMachine>

  class CustomOuterState : public QState
  {
     Q_OBJECT
  public:
     virtual void onEntry(QEvent * event)
     {
        // create inner state machine
        machine = new QStateMachine();
        /*
         * some operations with the machine
         */
     }
  private:
     QStateMachine* machine;
  };

  #endif
```

And test object which just emits a signal:

```
  #ifndef A_H
  #define A_H

  #include <QObject>

  class TestObject : public QObject
  {
     Q_OBJECT
  signals:
     void testObjectSignal();
  };

  #endif
```

So this code works as expected - the outer state machine goes from the first state to the final:

```
  QStateMachine(0x7fffc00f0a20) : Outer state machine first state  QSet(CustomOuterState(0xe0a380) ) 
  QStateMachine(0x7fffc00f0a20) : Outer state machine second state  QSet(QFinalState(0xe0a460) )
```

But with a little change inside the custom state - passing `this` (which is a subclass of `QState`) to the inner state machine constructor

```
  -        machine = new QStateMachine();
  +        machine = new QStateMachine(this);
```

results that the **outer** state machine doesn't want to make a transition - it stays in the first state although the transition signal was sent

```
  QStateMachine(0x7fff219edcb0) : Outer state machine first state  QSet(CustomOuterState(0x1fc4380) ) 
  QStateMachine(0x7fff219edcb0) : Outer state machine second state  QSet(CustomOuterState(0x1fc4380) )
```

The solution is simple - just delete the inner state machine and everything works. But the question is why the bad thing happens.

So, why adding `this` which is a subclass of `QState` to the **inner** state machine constructor results so that the **outer** state machine doesn't want to make a transition?

Comment: Problem can be because QStateMachine inhereted from QState class. QState class in consturctor can accept parent state, therefore, "this" pointer is a parent state for QStateMachine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to modify a state machine's statechart from a state's event handler. That's not supported by the state machine. Since `QStateMachine` is-a `QState`, by adding it as a child you're modifying the statechart.

When `onEntry` is called, the statechart looks as follows:
[image: statechart before]
During `onEntry`, you change it to something resembling the following. The `machine` is not an initial state, it's just a dangling, useless state.  Even if it weren't dangling, it'd still be unusable as it was added during a state transition.
[image: statechart after]

Since `QStateMachine` is a `QState`, when you make it a direct child of a state it becomes a substate of that state. If all you want is to use the state as a container for the state machine, you can insert an intervening non-state object between the parent and the state.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/statemachine-nested-32619103
#include <QtCore>

struct OuterState : QState
{
   QStateMachine * machine { nullptr };
   virtual void onEntry(QEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
   {
      // through an intervening container
      auto container = new QObject(this);
      machine = new QStateMachine(container);
   }
   OuterState(QState * parent = 0) : QState(parent) {}
};
```

Finally, the pseudo-synchronous code that invokes `processEvents` is unnecessary. You can do things when states are entered, etc. Recall that since a signal is an invokable method just like a slot is, you can connect signals to signals. In fact, since all you want to achieve is an unconditional transition, you might as well use one.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

   // create outer state machine with all states
   QStateMachine outerStateMachine;
   OuterState state1 { &outerStateMachine };
   QFinalState state2 { &outerStateMachine };
   state1.addTransition(&state2);
   outerStateMachine.setInitialState(&state1);
   outerStateMachine.start();

   a.connect(&state1, &QState::entered, []{ qDebug() << "state1 entered"; });
   a.connect(&state2, &QState::entered, []{ qDebug() << "state2 entered"; });
   a.connect(&state2, &QState::entered, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit);
   return a.exec();
}
```

The above is, more or less, how self-contained test cases should look: single file, no fluff and verbosity that detracts from the issue at hand.